# Radar fuel level sensor

Tags: fuel, radar, fuel-systems

Do any aircraft use radar to measure the level of fuel in their fuel tanks?

Comment: Aside from whether it would work or not (I have no idea) it seems that there are plenty of far simpler (= less expensive) ways to measure fuel quantity.

Comment: But why?????????

Comment: I use radar TLI's in many industrial/marine control systems but I'm not sure it would work in aircraft. Big problem is that they can't measure close to the sensor so they require a "hat" to offset them from the top of the tank.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of that kind of thing in aircraft in 40 years in the industry. Capacitance tubes are simple, very accurate, and solid state, that is, no moving parts, and work perfectly well, so there isn't really a need to go with a completely different technology.

Comment: Capacitance tubes work in space too. (see answers to [Remaining fuel estimation/measuring Strategy in a spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26853/12102))